# Erro de conversão ao enviar input ao controller para salvar

Tags: java, spring, controller, view

Boa noite pessoal, estou tendo dificuldade pra resolver esse problema, espero que possam me ajudar... Ao tentar salvar os dados vindo da View somente um campo retorna esse erro:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type com.sisdcon.oficinas.model.Usuarios for property corretor_heados;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert
>   value of type java.lang.String to required type
>   com.sisdcon.oficinas.model.Usuarios for property corretor_heados: no
>   matching editors or conversion strategy found

na tela tem mais 3 campos do mesmo tipo e funciona corretamente, abaixo deixo o Model, Controller (método de salvar) e o trecho da view (contendo os campos)

Model....

```
 @Table(name = "heados")
@Entity
public class Atendimentos {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id_heados;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "cadastro_heados", referencedColumnName = "id_cadastros", updatable = false, insertable = false)
   @NotNull(message = "Cliente Obrigatório.")
   private Cadastros cadastro_heados;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "veiculo_heados", referencedColumnName = "id_veiculos", updatable = false, insertable = false)
   @NotNull(message = "Veículo Obrigatório.")
   private Veiculos veiculo_heados;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "seguradora_heados", referencedColumnName = "id_cadastros", updatable = false, insertable = false)
   private Cadastros seguradora_heados;

   ?//--- ESTE É O CAMPO QUE OCORRE O ERRO!!!
   @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "corretor_heados", referencedColumnName = "id_usuarios", updatable = false, insertable = false)
   private Usuarios corretor_heados;


   private Long usuario_heados;
   private String veiculo_km_heados;
```

Controller... método de salvar

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String salvar(@Validated Atendimentos atendimentos, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

      System.out.println("vou tentar salvar");

      ///-- O SISTEMA ENTRA AQUI RETORNANDO O ERRO
      if (errors.hasErrors()) { 
         System.out.println("parei no erro!");
         return CADASTROVIEW;
      }
      try {

         atendimentosService.salvar(atendimentos);

      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
         return CADASTROVIEW;
      }

      return "redirect:/atendimentos/"+atendimentos.getId_heados();
   }
```

Trecho da view contento os campo

```
<form id="FormAtendimentos" method="POST" th:action="@{/atendimentos}" th:object="${atendimentos}">

   <input type="text" th:field="*{seguradora_heados}">

   <input type="text" th:field="*{veiculo_heados}">

    <!--  ESSE É O CAMPO QUE O SISTEMA RETORNA O ERRO    -->
   <input type="text" th:field="*{corretor_heados}"> 


</form>
```

Percebi que, somente ele ao preencher no caso de Edição, ele nao preenche com o ID da tabela "um número" ele preenche com a referencia ao model dessa forma...

```
com.sisdcon.oficinas.model.Usuarios@22120bd8
```

outra coisa é na query que o JPA monta, nela tenho varios joins, daí ele mesmo hora usa inner join ou left outer join..... abaixo deixo a query montada pelo JPA....

```
select
    atendiment0_.id_heados as id_heado1_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.cadastro_heados as cadastr25_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.corretor_heados as correto26_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.custosadicionais_heados as custosad2_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.dataentrada_heados as dataentr3_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.dataprevsaida_heados as dataprev4_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.datasaida_heados as datasaid5_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.deducao_heados as deducao_6_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.extramaoobra_heados as extramao7_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.extrapeca_heados as extrapec8_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.franquia_heados as franquia9_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.maoobra_heados as maoobra10_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.materialpintura_heados as materia11_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.obschecklist_heados as obschec12_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.obsextras_heados as obsextr13_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.seguradora_heados as segurad27_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.sinistronumero_heados as sinistr14_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.tipoatendimento_heados as tipoate15_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.usuario_heados as usuario16_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.veiculo_heados as veiculo28_5_0_,
    atendiment0_.veiculo_km_heados as veiculo17_5_0_,
    cadastros1_.id_cadastros as id_cadas6_0_1_,
    cadastros1_.bairro_cadastros as bairro_c7_0_1_,
    cadastros1_.cep_cadastros as cep_cada8_0_1_,
    cadastros1_.cidade_cadastros as cidade_c9_0_1_,
    cadastros1_.cpfcnpj_cadastros as cpfcnpj_2_0_1_,
    cadastros1_.dtnasc_cadastros as dtnasc_10_0_1_,
    cadastros1_.endereco_cadastros as enderec11_0_1_,
    cadastros1_.ie_cadastros as ie_cada12_0_1_,
    cadastros1_.nome_cadastros as nome_ca13_0_1_,
    cadastros1_.numero_cadastros as numero_14_0_1_,
    cadastros1_.razaosocial_cadastros as razaoso15_0_1_,
    cadastros1_.tipo_cadastros as tipo_cad5_0_1_,
    cadastros1_.uf_cadastros as uf_cada16_0_1_,
    usuarios2_.id_usuarios as id_usuar3_11_2_,
    usuarios2_.grupo_usuarios as grupo_us4_11_2_,
    usuarios2_.nome_usuarios as nome_usu5_11_2_,
    cadastros3_.id_cadastros as id_cadas6_0_3_,
    cadastros3_.bairro_cadastros as bairro_c7_0_3_,
    cadastros3_.cep_cadastros as cep_cada8_0_3_,
    cadastros3_.cidade_cadastros as cidade_c9_0_3_,
    cadastros3_.cpfcnpj_cadastros as cpfcnpj_2_0_3_,
    cadastros3_.dtnasc_cadastros as dtnasc_10_0_3_,
    cadastros3_.endereco_cadastros as enderec11_0_3_,
    cadastros3_.ie_cadastros as ie_cada12_0_3_,
    cadastros3_.nome_cadastros as nome_ca13_0_3_,
    cadastros3_.numero_cadastros as numero_14_0_3_,
    cadastros3_.razaosocial_cadastros as razaoso15_0_3_,
    cadastros3_.tipo_cadastros as tipo_cad5_0_3_,
    cadastros3_.uf_cadastros as uf_cada16_0_3_,
    veiculos4_.id_veiculos as id_veicu1_12_4_,
    veiculos4_.ano_veiculos as ano_veic2_12_4_,
    veiculos4_.cor_veiculos as cor_veic3_12_4_,
    veiculos4_.modelo_veiculos as modelo_v4_12_4_,
    veiculos4_.motor_veiculos as motor_ve5_12_4_,
    veiculos4_.placa_veiculos as placa_ve6_12_4_,
    veiculosmo5_.id_veiculosmodelos as id_veicu3_14_5_,
    veiculosmo5_.marca_veiculosmodelos as marca_ve5_14_5_,
    veiculosmo5_.nome_veiculosmodelos as nome_vei4_14_5_ 
from
    heados atendiment0_ 
inner join
    cadastros cadastros1_ 
        on atendiment0_.cadastro_heados=cadastros1_.id_cadastros 
left outer join
    usuarios usuarios2_ 
        on atendiment0_.corretor_heados=usuarios2_.id_usuarios 
left outer join
    cadastros cadastros3_ 
        on atendiment0_.seguradora_heados=cadastros3_.id_cadastros 
inner join
    veiculos veiculos4_ 
        on atendiment0_.veiculo_heados=veiculos4_.id_veiculos 
left outer join
    veiculosmodelos veiculosmo5_ 
        on veiculos4_.modelo_veiculos=veiculosmo5_.id_veiculosmodelos 
where
    atendiment0_.id_heados=?
```

Caso precisem de mais alguma informação por favor solicitar,

Agradeço desde já!!!

Obgriado!

Renato Muniz.

Comment: Nenhuma sugestão galera!?

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver somente agora, e o que ocorreu é que é obrigatório 
ter um Repository mesmo que vazio, eu somente criava quando queria fazer uma pesquisa manual, ou seja, criar uma query personalizada, depois que criei o Repository mesmo que vazio, funfou!!! 
pra qm passar pelo mesmo problema tente isso aí!!
Valeu!!!